Release a web application from visual studio and install in specified location in another system
I am releasing a web application from Visual Studio using "publish app" and want to install in a specified location in another system. It is installing in C:/ by default but I want to install it in any user-specified location. How can I give the path to the desired installation location?

Does this answer your question? My program has been "published", how can I change the installation path?
